# "command not found" using line in argument to os.system using python

Tags: python, linux

I am new to python and working on some xyz project where i am taking the day-1 dated report, fetching the data and redirecting it into another file on linux machine

here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

cur_date = os.popen("date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%m%d'").read()
print (cur_date)
os.system('zgrep "919535144580" /var/tmp/comp?/emse_revres_rdc.log.%s* | grep -v "RI" | cut -d "|" -f 9,10,23,24,26 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr >> /var/tmp/Andy/test.txt'%cur_date)
```

it is printing below error.

```
20180731

**gzip: /var/tmp/comp?/emse_revres_rdc.log.20180731.gz: No such file or directory
sh: line 1: 1: command not found**
```

but when i am executing the same in shell it is running absolutely fine or if i manually give the date and run the above, it runs successfully.

Please provide your suggestions on the same.

Comment: Looks like you aren't trimming the trailing newline from `cur_date`'s output. Is there a reason you're using a separate `os.popen()` call, vs a command substitution in the shell (which will do that automatically)?

Comment: ...which is to say that this doesn't actually have anything to do with the `*`; the problem is the `%s` you substitute ending with a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `*` has nothing to do with the problem; the string you're substituting with `%s` ends with a newline, and *that newline* is what breaks your code.**

When you use `os.popen('...').read()`, you get the *entire* output of `...` -- including the trailing newline, which shell command substitutions implicitly trim.

The *best* answer would be to rewrite your logic in Python, but the *easy* answer here is to use such a command substitution, which also avoids trying to pass values into a script via string substitution (which is a fast route to shell-injection security bugs):

```
shell_script = r'''
cur_date=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%m%d')

zgrep "919535144580" /var/tmp/comp?/emse_revres_rdc.log."$cur_date"* \
  | grep -v "RI" \
  | cut -d "|" -f 9,10,23,24,26 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | sort -nr \
  >> /var/tmp/Andy/test.txt
'''

os.system(shell_script)
```

That said, if you're just going for the shortest change possible, put the following before your original code's `os.system()` call:

```
cur_date = cur_date.rstrip('\n')
```